Как объединить два графика функций на graphtoy.com
Разбираюсь с этой статьей , остановился на первой функции. Пытаюсь изобразить ее вот тут  У функции два выхода. С выходом return (a*t + b)*t*t + n; я разобрался, просто подставил единицы куда нужно и графтой нарисовал мне. С выражением return x; тоже все понятно, просто рисуется y = f(x). Но как записывается функция, которая включает в себя и это условие if( x>m ) return x; ? Т.е. отдельно два графика я нарисовал, а как нарисовать график с одним выражением? Пробовал clamp, разные варианты получались, но не подошли.

Ну там же ссылку на пример если открыть, то видно, что через cond(условие,если_да,если_нет) это делается. То есть что-то типа cond(x>1, x, (x-1)*x^2+1), например.

Вот спасибо @CrazyElf ! Я даже не догадался оттуда открыть пример! Искал подходящую функцию среди кнопок внизу справа, но не нашел, и cond() там почему-то там нет. А еще мне хотелось найти алгебраическое выражение этой функции, но я не знаю даже, насколько это сложно или просто. Но раз есть cond(), наверное вопрос решен. Но как быть с алгебраическим выражением, это вообще просто решается?

Вот решение с помощью функции cond():  ссылка

Алгебраически что-то я не уверен, что такое можно... Хотя если можно получить знак выражения, то можно дальше превратить плюс в 1, минус в 0 и умножать на это. А для другой части наоборот. Но это будет выглядеть несколько громоздко, с условным оператором проще гораздо. В общем, если доступен оператор знака выражения или хотя бы модуль, то можно, но выглядеть будет некрасиво.

Добавьте свой ответ с тем, что получилось, я за него проголосую. И хорошо бы скриншоты графиков добавить в вопрос и в ответ. Может кому ещё пригодится.

Вот решение с помощью функции cond().
В интерфейсе сайта графтой просто нет такой кнопки для cond(). Но если у вас есть решение, как написать такую функцию алгебраически - мне будет интересно.
Вот функция:
float almostIdentity( float x, float m, float n )
{
    if( x>m ) return x;
    float a = 2.0*n - m;
    float b = 2.0*m - 3.0*n;
    float t = x/m;
    return (a*t + b)*t*t + n;
}

Вот формула для graphtoy.com (при m = n = 1):
cond(x>1, x, (x-1)*x^2+1)

Вот ее график:


Всё-таки вставьте в ответ саму функцию и хорошо бы ещё скриншот что получается.
